# How do I set my Yongnuo YN-622C II triggers so that I can put my 580EX II into Manual mode?

Tags: yongnuo, wireless-flash, triggers, 580exii

Recently I've been using the Yongnuo YN-622C II in connection with the Canon 580EX II in manual mode.

Everything worked fine. I could change settings in my camera setup screen to which the flash would take over. The flash was in Manual mode, the transmitter/receiver units both on C2 and 622 mode.

But then I forgot my triggers at an assignment and it was gone.
I bought another 622 set and tried to set everything up the same but I came across several issues:

First issue

I can't put the flash settings on manual mode in my speedlight settings screen in my camera. It switches back to e-ttl mode...something I do not want.

Second issue

The moment I turned on my flash I held down the zoom button so I could enter the flash master/slave settings. When I was finished and half-pressed the shutter button the whole master/slave/channel information all were gone and the flash switched back to e-ttl mode cause apparently since I could not change the flash settings to manual in my speedlights settings menu it takes over the e-ttl mode.

With my former set of 622s I never had this problem but I do remember I also had a hard time finally getting the right settings.

Does someone have a clue what I am doing wrong here?

Normally I should be able to change from e-ttl to manual mode in speedlight settings menu and when I connect my 580EX II directly to my camera that is the case (just tested it). But the moment I'm using the triggers it suddenly becomes impossible.

I do a lot of club nightlife photography and this was such a great way of using the 580EX II. I could easily change manual output settings in my speedlight settings on my camera without having to go through the flash settings.

I hope someone can help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that the flash is set to "neutral" default settings. If it isn't, whatever setting you've set on the flash's control panel will override the trigger. Ditto for the trigger. If it's set to anything other than "neutral" default settings, it will override whatever you enter using the camera's menu.

In E-TTL mode the flash and trigger should be set to "0" FEC/FEB. Any other value, such as +1 or -1/3 FEC, and the flash or trigger will override the camera.

In manual power mode it should be set to 1/1. Any other setting, such as 1/2 or 1/4, and the flash/trigger will override the camera.

Flash zoom head should be set to "Auto". Any other value...